# document.getElementByID not a function Quick fix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm studying for an exam and I'm doing some sample problems by myself. I've ran into the Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function problem.

Here is my code:

```
   <script>
function checkValidity(){
    //Create variable to check for errors
    var input = document.getElementByID('myID').value;

    if(input < 0){
        document.getElementByID('errorCheck').textContent = 'The value must be a positive integer';
    }else if(ifNaN(input)){
        document.getElementByID('errorCheck').textContent = 'Not a number. The value must be a positive integer.';
    }else if(input == null){
        document.getElementByID('errorCheck').textContent = 'Please input a value.';
    } else{
        document.getElementByID('errorCheck').textContent = 'Valid number.';
    }
}

document.getElementByID('validateid').onclick = checkValidity;
```

It yells at me at this line of code saying it is invalid.

```
document.getElementByID('validateid').onclick = checkValidity;
```

I know its a small mistake. I'd appreciate if someone pointed it out.

Comment: `isNaN`, not`ifNaN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `document.getElementById`, lowercase d.

Comment: I appreciate it. I typed it wrong once and Sublime finishes the rest of them for me. Can't believe I didn't catch that.

Comment: @Logan As this or the other identical answer apparently solves your problem, please accept one so this is marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a typo. You need to do:

```
document.getElementById('errorCheck')
```

with lowercase 'd'. Here is a reference [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).